# Sample out from Database while typing PHP or JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, textbox, addition

I wrote a website that adds information to a Mysql Database. But I want to sample out some lines of the database while I'm typing the information into textboxes.

I have a database with 3 rows : A, B, C, 
I type in A and after I switch to the textbox for the row B, a script ( PHP or JavaScript ) 
shows my a list of all the lines in the table with the row A i typed in.

How can i do this with PHP/javascript ?

I know that it is a little hard to understand so just ask if you're don't understand something.

Greetings Jeff

Comment: Well, you need to learn about "ajax" to send request to server and get data in the background. To make life easier use jquery or some library.

Comment: To expand on Venu. Ajax is essentially using javascript to call a php (or ASP, etc) script in the background which can then return data. You can do what you want fairly easily, using an onchange event to trigger the javascript (or trigger a timer, and the timer triggers the javascript half a second later if the content of the text box hasn't changed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the frameworks you are using in your project, there are several functions that can do it for you.
For dojo: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/FilteringSelect.html#dijit-form-filteringselect

jquery can do the same:
http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/